# Bash split large file into smaller files

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell

So I want to split up a rather large file into several little ones based on the 8th column. So I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
run_command(){
eval ${1}
wait
}
chInput=("1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "Z" "T" "G" "F" "A" "D" "P")
sampInput=("heyA")

for ((x=0;x<${#chInput[@]};x++));do
com="awk -F'\t' '$8=="${chInput[x]}"' /home/location/"$sampInput"_This_P.txt > "$sampInput"Ch"${chInput[x]}".txt"
run_command "${com}"
done
```

But it isn't working because of

> '$8=="

```
awk: ==1
awk: ^ syntax error
awk: ==2
awk: ^ syntax error
awk: ==3
awk: ^ syntax error
awk: ==4
awk: ^ syntax error
```

But just doing

```
awk -F'\t' '$8==1' /home/location/heyA_This_P.txt > Ch1.txt
```

from the command line did work

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The acute problem is the double quotes; `$8` will be substituted by something (probably nothing at all) at the time you assign the variable.  You could try to use single quotes with proper escaping, but the real solution would probably be to take a deep breath and start over without having either `eval` or the Awk script in a variable.

What is the purpose of this pretzel logic, anyway?  You should probably read, and take to heart, the advice in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Here is a quick attempt at resolving your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

chInput=("1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "Z" "T" "G" "F" "A" "D" "P")
sampInput=("heyA")

for ((x=0;x<${#chInput[@]};x++));do
    awk -F'\t' '$8=="'"${chInput[x]}"'"' /home/location/"$sampInput"_This_P.txt > "$sampInput"Ch"${chInput[x]}".txt
done
```

Notice in particular the construct for interpolating `"${chInput[X]}"` into the script (that's really the only thing I changed, actually, apart from removing the variable and the `eval` stuff).  That's a string in single quotes, adjacent to a string in double quotes, adjacent to a string in single quotes, which evaluate to a single string in Bash.  So `'foo'"bar"'baz'` evaluates to `foobarbaz` and similarly `'"foo"'` adjacent to `"'bar'"` evaluates to `"foo"'bar'`.  Here, `'$8=="'` adjacent to `"${chInput[x]}"` adjacent to `'"'` evaluates to `$8=="..."` where the stuff in the double quotes is substituted at the time of the assignment.

(You don't really need the array, either; you could just do

```
for c in "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "11" "12" \
         "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "Z" "T" "G" "F" \
         "A" "D" "P"
do
    awk -F'\t' '$8=="'"$c"'"' /home/location/"$sampInput"_This_P.txt > "${sampInput}Ch$c.txt"
done
```

and be compatible with Classic Bourne shell.)

Comment: The reason I was trying this is because I am running a comparison between this file and another and the program was hanging up on this file because of the size of it. I wanted to play around and see if I could take the lazy way out and split the file rather than rewrite some code. I read some articles that said it would work, some that said it wouldn't and I wanted to see for myself